# How to synchronise data between Sugar ORM and Room library?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, orm, android-room, android-mvvm

I have an app that currently uses Sugar ORM version 1.5 to manage the SQL database. My goal is to slowly rewrite the whole app using MVVM, Room and Kotlin. Because I can't at the moment delete the Sugar ORM I am looking for some way how to synchronise data between these two databases until I rewrite the whole app. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it sounds doable. I am assuming it's a "live" app that has a certain user base?

The first step would probably be creating an abstraction of the database. "Hide" `Sugar ORM` behind some interface(`Repository` pattern basically). Make sure everything works just as before but this time the client (app) won't know what `Sugar` is.

The next step would probably be copying all of the data from `Sugar` to the newly created `Room`. At this point, the `Repository` should still use `Sugar` as the main source of data but should also pass all of the queries to the `Room` as well((C)inserts&Updates but you can also track cases when the result of Read mismatches). This should allow you to watch for any discrepancies in data between them to discover possible problems.

After some time without any apparent problems(data mismatched), you should be able to just remove `Sugar` in one fell swoop without it affecting anything.

Comment: Hi there, you're right it is a live app. Could you advise me on how to create the Repository for the Sugar ORM that uses Java language only? 

The Sugar ORM  .save() operation is in the public class SugarRecord and this class is read-only so I can't add any code there.

I assume that I have to create some kind of "bridge" between sending data from Sugar ORM to Room and from Room to Sugar ORM because the Sugar ORM uses Java only and the Room will be using Kotlin.

Comment: The explanation and discussion if very much beyond SO question/answer - you can ask me in [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248961/question-74141011-sugar-orm-and-kotlin)

Comment: Thank you for your offer, unfortunately, I have to have reputation >=20 to use the Chat Room.

Comment: Ok, nvm. What I wanted to say is that Kotlin and Java are interoperable. You can use Java call from Sugar ORM in Kotlin.

Comment: The main challenge here is that I inherit an app where someone creates .save () everywhere for every table, which means I have to find all .save() for all tables and create some kind of bridge. In that bridge, I have to do for every table find out if the .save() means to insert, edit or something else and then do the job. It is a massive job if you have 12 tables and 300 .save(). I was hoping to have all the information somehow from the public class SugarRecord that is read-only.

Comment: It will require a lot of effort no matter what you do but first step, as I said should be creating abstraction/bridge that will still use Sugar .